# Invalid layer id

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layer

I have project that is made in one of previous versions of Unity and after I upgraded it in Unity 5.4 I'm getting this error all the time:

*Invalid layer id. Please use the unique id of the layer (which is not the same as its index in the list).*

I have research about this but I can't find any proper answer. So I thought maybe someone had similar problem.

If needed I can provide more informations. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It looks like you need to generally learn about Layers ... it's a fundamental part of Unity3D https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html

Comment: I have a function in which I'm checking is SpriteRenderer equal to null and than I was trying to set sortingLayerID by passing the number and that was working in Unity 4.6 but in Unity 5 I had error abowe I don't know why. I thought it's not because of code. But then I used sortingLayerName passing the name and it's working now. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all your layers in

```
Edit -> Project Settings -> Tags & Layers
```

You can find a layer id from its name

```
int id = LayerMask.NameToLayer("layer name");
```

Also you can (and you should) use name instead of id almost everywhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks you pointed me to the right direction. I have a function in which I'm checking is SpriteRenderer equal to null and than I was trying to set sortingLayerID by passing the number and that was working in Unity 4.6 but in Unity 5 I had error abowe I don't know why. But then I used sortingLayerName passing the name and it's working now. Thanks man!